# Global pgfplotset messing up error bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a plot with some error bars generated with this code, but the error bars are messed up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
every axis/.append style={
scale only axis,   
},
/tikz/every picture/.append style={
baseline,
trim axis left,
trim axis right,
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.5in,
height=3.5in,
scale only axis,
xmode=log,
xmin=0.001,
xmax=1,
xminorticks=true,
ymin=0,
ymax=250
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
 plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
 table[row sep=crcr, y error plus index=2, y error minus index=3]{0.0625469 25.07   0.25    0.25\\
0.0390918   54.77   0.649999999999999   0.649999999999999\\
0.0244324   154.33  1.5 1.5\\
0.0152702   200 5.5 5.5\\
0.00954391  208.67  5.5 5.5\\
0.00596494  215.33  6   6\\
0.00372809  219 2.5 2.5\\
0.00233006  220.67  5   5\\
0.00145628  221 1.5 1.5\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image: plot]

But if I remove

```
\pgfplotsset{
every axis/.append style={
scale only axis,   
},
/tikz/every picture/.append style={
baseline,
trim axis left,
trim axis right,
    }
}
```

It looks fine. The problem is like that `pgfplotset` command early in my document to control all alignment and axis trimming. Any solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the arguments `trim axis left` and `trim axis right` from the `pgfplotsset` to the `tikzpicture` environment:

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
every axis/.append style={
scale only axis,   
},
/tikz/every picture/.append style={
baseline,
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,
trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.5in,
height=3.5in,
scale only axis,
xmode=log,
xmin=0.001,
xmax=1,
xminorticks=true,
ymin=0,
ymax=250
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
 plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
 table[row sep=crcr, y error index=2, y error index=3]{0.0625469 25.07   0.25    0.25\\
0.0390918   54.77   0.649999999999999   0.649999999999999\\
0.0244324   154.33  1.5 1.5\\
0.0152702   200 5.5 5.5\\
0.00954391  208.67  5.5 5.5\\
0.00596494  215.33  6   6\\
0.00372809  219 2.5 2.5\\
0.00233006  220.67  5   5\\
0.00145628  221 1.5 1.5\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Whats with the `\[` when you meant just `[`? Also, might be useful to consider automating this solution as it seems the OP _always_ wants those options.

Comment: @PeterGrill -- I don't know why it gets there, my PC does not have it. I will re-post it soon.

Comment: @Jesse Hi, thanks yes this does work. It is probably the solution but as mentioned by Peter it would be nice if I can globally define trim axis left and right in the preamble. Thanks

Comment: @SteveHatcher -- Actually, in your current setting, mark out `trim axis left` would work too in my exhausted test. I observed `trim left` is the culprit because if you mark out the other one and leave trim left alone, the problem persists. To me that is not logic, so I proposed the current solution, moving them to the tikz environment. Hope this info helps.